# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tensor_type'

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, torchtext, opennmt

I am trying to run a code that was used with older versions of torch and torchtext. I have adjusted a lot in the code to make it work. I was able to pre-process and train my data. Lastly I tried to run the test script, after solving multiple errors, I am getting this error:

```
Batch size > 1 not implemented! Falling back to batch_size = 1 ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "translate_mm.py", line 166, in <module>
    main()
  File "translate_mm.py", line 84, in main
    onmt.ModelConstructor.load_test_model(opt, dummy_opt.__dict__)
  File "/onmt/ModelConstructor.py", line 145, in load_test_model
    checkpoint['vocab'], data_type=opt.data_type)
  File "/onmt/io/IO.py", line 57, in load_fields_from_vocab
    fields = get_fields(data_type, n_src_features, n_tgt_features)
  File "/onmt/io/IO.py", line 43, in get_fields
    return TextDataset.get_fields(n_src_features, n_tgt_features)
  File "/onmt/io/TextDataset.py", line 218, in get_fields
    postprocessing=make_src, sequential=False)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tensor_type'
```

I have tried downgrading to older versions of PyTorch, however when doing this I get a ModuleError namely:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchtext.legacy'
```

I have also tried running it on Anaconda, with proper pytorch and torchtext versions according to requirements, but there I get an entirely different error:

```
import torch._dl as _dl_flags ImportError: No module named _dl
```

I just need to test the data at this point, everything else seems to have worked out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-U

Answer (score 0):

The older versions of torchtext do not have a legacy module, so if you remove that part of the call that should fix the error.

i.e. `torchtext.legacy.___` -> `torchtext.___`